# db:migrate hangs on simple migration

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, dbmigrate

I am using PostgreSQL, Rails 3.1.3 and Ruby 1.9.3. I am struggling to use `db:migrate` as outlined [here](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-and-viewing-users-one#code%3aemail_uniqueness_index).

This is what I am seeing in the terminal:

```
funkdified@funkdified-laptop:~/railsprojects/hartl$ bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace 
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time) 
** Invoke environment (first_time) 
** Execute environment 
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time) 
** Invoke rails_env (first_time) 
** Execute rails_env 
** Execute db:load_config 
** Execute db:migrate 
== AddEmailUniquenessIndex: migrating ======================================== 
-- add_index(:users, :email, {:unique=>true})
```

and then the code hangs at this point. Any ideas why?

From: development.log

```
[1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m [1mSHOW search_path[0m 
[1m[35m (0.5ms)[0m SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations"
Migrating to CreateUsers (20120124022843) 
Migrating to AddEmailUniquenessIndex (20120124093922) 
[1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m [1mBEGIN[0m 
[1m[35m (3.6ms)[0m SELECT distinct i.relname, d.indisunique, d.indkey, t.oid 
FROM pg_class t 
INNER JOIN pg_index d ON t.oid = d.indrelid 
INNER JOIN pg_class i ON d.indexrelid = i.oid 
WHERE i.relkind = 'i' 
AND d.indisprimary = 'f' 
AND t.relname = 'users' 
AND i.relnamespace IN (SELECT oid FROM pg_namespace WHERE nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false)) ) 
ORDER BY i.relname
```

Comment: Can you log in a an appropriately privileged PostgreSQL user, and do `select * from pg_stat_activity`

Comment: I sure can. I've just executed this query through pgAdmin III:                -- Executing query:
select * from pg_stat_activity
Total query runtime: 11 ms.
4 rows retrieved.

Comment: @derobert, thanks for your response, but the migration has worked for me this morning. Nothing different - same migration file. Perhaps the computer just needed a restart? Strange.

Comment: Well, glad it worked... Its possible PosgreSQL's autovacuum or auto-stats collection kicked in overnight. BTW: The idea of the pg_stat_activity select was that you'd see what query the migration was running. Sort of defeated when you just pasted the row count, without the rows...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had same problem .. I found out that there was idle transaction which blocked further queries on this table ..

Run:

```
heroku pg:ps --app=...
```

To view database processes. You will have to kill idle process:

```
heroku pg:kill 913 --force --app=...
```

(913 is ID of idle process -> change it to your needs)

Comment: Before running this stuff, try the migration after ctrl c'ing your rails server and any open rails consoles if you have them.

Answer (score 17):

I just had a similar problem, where a very simple migration was stalling for no apparent reason. I believe the problem has to do with not being able to get a database connection. I exited a rails console session that I had open in another terminal and then the migration immediately finished with no problems.

Comment: My solution was the same as well. I closed my connection in another terminal tab and the migration ended immediately.

Comment: Same here. I've been facing this issue several times and it was because I had a rails console terminal window in another tab. Closed it, run migration and it succesfully finished.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and after trying a bunch of solutions what worked was...shutting down all of my terminal sessions, restarting the computer, and trying again. Sometimes it's just power cycle magic.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I just made two migrations. The first one created a new table, the second one removed fields from an existing table. The second migration was hanging, and the reason turned out to be a rails console session (`rails console --sandbox`) running in another terminal windows.